# Convert and rearrange List<>

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a list of Training which includes List of Subjects and each subject includes list of Users as follow :

```
internal class Training
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Subject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    internal class User
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

    }
```

Now i had to write another class that will return list of Distinct Users and all their training and subjects as follow:

```
internal class UserData
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public List<string> SubjectNames { get; set; }
        public List<string> TrainingNames { get; set; }
    }
```

From the training and subjects i only need their names.

I already wrote the part that reads the database and returns `List<Training>`  now how can i convert it to `List<UserData>`?

*Example*:

**Input**:

```
List<Training> trainings;
```

- Training ==> .NET
- - Subject ==> MVC
- - - User ==> Mike
- - - User ==> John
- - Subject ==> ASP.NET
- - - User ==> Mike
- - - User ==> Kim
- Training ==> Java
- - Subject ==> EJB
- - - User ==> Mike
- - - User ==> Kim

**Output**

```
List<UserData> usersData;
```

- UserData==> Mike
- - Training ==> .NET
- - Training ==> Java
- - Subject ==> MVC
- - Subject ==> ASP.NET
- - Subject ==> EJB
- UserData==> John
- - Training ==> .NET
- - Subject ==> MVC
- UserData==> Kim
- - Training ==> .NET
- - Training ==> Java
- - Subject ==> ASP.NET
- - Subject ==> EJB

Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Post what you have already tried.

Comment: Your model is confusing - you have a 1:n relationship form User:Training (through Subject) but want to store one "TrainingNames" value per User?

Comment: @DStanley you are right, I made a mistake (sorry for that) I modified my code.

Comment: @Maess All I did was a lot of for loops I will check the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<UserData> userDataList = trainings
    .Select(training => 
    {
        var distUsers = training.Subjects.SelectMany(ts => ts.Users)  // flatten out all users
            .GroupBy(u => new { u.UserId, u.FullName})                // group by u.UserId and u.FullName
            .Select(grp => grp.First());                              // take simply the first
        return new { training, users = distUsers };                   // return this anonymous type
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.users                                          // flatten out all distinct users
        .Select(u => new UserData                                     // for each create an instance of UserData  
        {
            UserId = u.UserId,
            FullName = u.FullName,
            SubjectNames = x.training.Subjects.Select(s => s.Name).ToList(), // select only the name and create a list
            TrainingNames = x.training.Name
        }))
    .ToList();  // create the final list
```

**Edit**: according to your changed requirement that your `TrainingName`(s) is actually a `List<string>` (which changes all). I would implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<User>` which you can use for `Distinct` and `GroupBy`(for example):

```
public class UserComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User x, User y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null ||y == null) return false;
        return x.UserId == y.UserId && x.FullName == y.FullName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(User obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.UserId ?? "").GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (obj.FullName ?? "").GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then following query should work:

```
var uComparer = new UserComparer();
var distinctUsers = trainings
    .SelectMany(t => t.Subjects.SelectMany(ts => ts.Users))
    .Distinct(uComparer);
List<UserData> userData = distinctUsers
    .SelectMany(u => 
    {
        var subjectsWithUser = trainings
            .SelectMany(t => t.Subjects
                .Where(ts => ts.Users
                    .Any(tsu => tsu.UserId == u.UserId && tsu.FullName == u.FullName)))
                .Select(ts => new { user = u, training = t, subject = ts });
        return subjectsWithUser;
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.user, uComparer)
    .Select(grp => new UserData
    {
        UserId = grp.Key.UserId, FullName = grp.Key.FullName,
        TrainingNames = grp.Select(xx => xx.training.Name).Distinct().ToList(),
        SubjectNames = grp.Select(xx => xx.subject.Name).Distinct().ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Correct and readable. One thing to note (just matter of taste) - you can return new anonymous object directly from lambda `training => new { training, users = /* distinc users query */ }` and avoid creating local variable and usage of `return` - I find returns in lambdas very distracting :)

Comment: Thanks @Tim, the last line TrainingNames = x.training.Name, in fact TrainingNames is a collection. how can i set it?

Comment: @Maro: Why is it a `List<string>` now? The origin is `trainings` which is a  _"list of Training"_ (`List<Training>`). So for every training i select all subject's users. It's not clear how and which trainings you want to take.

Comment: @TimSchmelter In my original post i made a mistake, normally i want to have a list of users in each user should have list of training and list of subjects. each user can be in have multiple subject and multiple training. I hope it's more clear

Comment: @Maro: that's changing all, i have not the time now to get a deeper insight. Maybe you could edit your question to provide simple sample data and a desired result. That makes it clearer.

Comment: @Maro: i've tried something, not sure if it works but it might give you an idea anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46329/discussion-between-maro-and-tim-schmelter)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for efforts +1 from me however i found 2 issues 
- (fixed) `if (x != null || y != null) return false;` which make the Equal function returns always false.
- the second is that in the line `.Select(ts => new { user = u, training = ts, subject = ts });` ts is the subject so there is no training names returned here. I will try to fix the second one. thanks again for your support

Comment: @Maro: fixed it, you have to use the `t` variable instead of `ts`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of,

```
var usersData = trainings
    .SelectMany(
        training => training.Subjects.Select(
            subject => new { TrainingName = training.Name, Subject = subject })
    .SelectMany(
        subject => subject.Users.Select(
            user => new { TrainingName = training.Name, SubjectName = subject.Name, User = user })
    .GroupBy(user => user.User)
    .Select(grouping => new UserData 
                {
                    UserId = grouping.Key.UserId,
                    FullName = grouping.Key.FullName,
                    TrainingName = grouping.Select(user => user.TrainingName), 
                    SubjectName = grouping.Select(user => user.SubjectName )
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

First flatten to a list of `Training/Subject/Users`, then group by user:

```
lstTraining.SelectMany(t => t.Subjects, (t, s) => new{t,s})
           .SelectMany(ts => ts.s.Users, (ts, u) => new{ts.t, ts.s, u})
           .GroupBy(tsu => tsu.u)
           .Select(g => new UserData 
                      {
                      UserId = g.Key.UserId,
                      FullName = g.Key.FullName,
                      SubjectNames = g.Select(tsu => tsu.s.Name)
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .ToList(),
                      TrainingNames = g.Select(tsu => tsu.t.Name)
                                       .Distinct()
                                       .ToList()
                     }

                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?
Assuming that Users.Contains(u) will work fine, which means the Users are accurately "comparable".
Assuming that TrainingNames should be a concatenation of training names related to the user.
It looks long because I indented the code (nearly) as much as possible in hope to make it more readable.

```
            internal List<UserData> ConverToUserDataList(List<Training> TrainingList, List<Subject> AllSubjects)
    {
        List<UserData> userDataList = new List<UserData>();
        IEnumerable<Subject> usersSubjects;
        TrainingList.ForEach
        (
            training =>
                training.Subjects.ForEach
                (
                    subject =>
                        subject.Users.ForEach
                        (
                            user =>
                                {
                                    usersSubjects = AllSubjects.Where(subjectB => subjectB.Users.Contains(user));
                                    userDataList.Add
                                    (
                                        new UserData
                                        {
                                            UserId = user.UserId,
                                            FullName = user.FullName,
                                            SubjectNames = usersSubjects.Select(subjectB => subjectB.Name).ToList(),
                                            TrainingNames = string.Join(
                                                                            ",",
                                                                            TrainingList.Where(trainingB => trainingB.Subjects.Intersect(usersSubjects).Any()).Select(trainingB => trainingB.Name).ToList()
                                                                        )
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                        )
                )
        );
        return userDataList;
    }
```